# Display some values with Django templates from dict with lists and dicts

Tags: python, django-templates

I've a trouble to display some values from this dictionnary :

```
my_dict = {"temperature": [0,10], 
"gradient": [{"data":[{"start": 10, "end": 12}], "unit": "°C"}, {"data":[{"start": 12, "end": 15}], "unit": "°C"}]}
```

I would like to use the values from the key "gradient" by displaying value 10 (key "start") and value 12 (key "end"), then value 12 (second key "start") and value 15 (second key "end") in my HTML page with Django templates.
How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
{% for gradient_dic in my_dict.gradient %}
    {% for data_dic in gradient_dic.data %}
        Start = {{data_dic.start}}
        Stop = {{data_dic.stop}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```